# Can't mail multiple Body-lines in PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a problem using the PHPmailer. I use a form and create multiple lines to send with PHPmailer using $mail->Body, like this:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
include_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
include_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";
include_once "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1252');
$message = "";
$content = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $naam = $_POST['naam'];
    $adres = $_POST['adres'];
    $woonplaats = $_POST['woonplaats'];
    $land = $_POST['land'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $aantal = $_POST['aantal'];
    $verzenden = $_POST['verzenden'];
    $opmerkingen = $_POST['opmerkingen'];
    $jaar = substr(date("y"),-1);
    if ($verzenden == "afhalen"){
       $verzendkosten = "0.00";
    } else {
       $verzendkosten = "6.50";
    }
    $subtotaal = $aantal * 37.50;
    $totaal = $subtotaal + $verzendkosten;
    $BTW = $totaal * 0.173554;
    $weergavetotaal = number_format($totaal, 2, ',', '.');
    $weergavesubtotaal = number_format($subtotaal, 2, ',', '.');
    $weergaveBTW = number_format($BTW, 2, ',', '.');
    $weergaveverzendkosten = number_format($verzendkosten, 2, ',', '.');
    // IP van de verstuurder 
    $ip = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipa = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
        $ip = 'ONBEKEND';            
    $factuurip = substr($ip,-2);
    $factuurmin = substr(date('i'),-1);   
    $content = "" .$naam. "<br>";
    $content .= "" .$adres. "<br>";
    $content .= "" .$woonplaats. "<br>";
    $content .= "" .$land. "<br>";
    $content .= "e-Mail: " .$email. "<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>";
    $content .= "FACTUUR <br>&nbsp;<br>";
    $content .= "Factuurdatum: ".date("j-m-Y")."<br>";
    $content .= "Factuurnummer: " .$jaar. "" .date("md"). "-" .$factuurip. "" .$factuurmin. "<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>";
    $content .= "Hartelijke dank voor de volgende bestelling:  <br>";
    $content .= "_________________________________________________________________________  <br>&nbsp;<br>";
    $content .= "" .$aantal. " Stuk(s) Siberisch Stenenorakel a 37,50 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . € " .$weergavesubtotaal. "<br>&nbsp;<br>";
    $content .= "Bijdrage in de verzendkosten . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . € " .$weergaveverzendkosten. "<br>";
    $content .= "Levering: ".$verzenden." <br>&nbsp;<br>"; 
    $content .= "_________________________________________________________________________  <br>&nbsp;<br>";
    $content .= "BTW 21% € " .$weergaveBTW. " . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Totaal  € " .$weergavetotaal. "<br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>";
    $content .= "Uw bestelling is definitief zodra het totaalbedrag van € " .$weergavetotaal. " <br>";         
    $content .= "is ontvangen o.v.v. het bovenstaande factuurnummer*  <br>&nbsp;<br>";
    $content .= "Uw opmerkingen: <br>";
    $content .= "" .$opmerkingen. "<br>&nbsp;<br>";
    $content .= "*Zonder tegenbericht bedraagt de levertermijn enkele dagen.  <br>";
    $content .= "*Afhalen alleen op afspraak. Bij afhalen is PIN-betaling mogelijk.  <br>"; 
    $content .= "Dit formulier is ingevuld vanaf IP-nummer " .$ip. " op ".date("j M Y")." om ".date("G:i")."<br>&nbsp;<br>"; 
    $message = $content;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    //if we want to send via SMTP
    $mail->Host = "smtp.mail.pcextreme.nl";
    //$mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "mail@domain.com";
    $mail->Password = "passsword";
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "TLS"; //SSL
    $mail->Port = 587; //465
    $mail->addAddress($email, $naam);
    $mail->setFrom('mail@domain.com');
    $mail->Subject = "Bestelling Siberisch Stenenorakel";
    $mail->isHTML(true);
            $mail->Body = $message;
    if ($mail->send()) {
      echo $message;
            }    
}
```

?>

When I echo it to the screen it looks good, but it will only send when I use no more then 3 lines. It doesn't matter which 3 lines. Any suggestions? Gr Jabson

Update: I posted the complete code now. Echo on the screen is ok, but it will only send mail when I limit the number of lines to max. 3.  Gr Jabson

Comment: (How) have you verified that it doesn’t send the mail, and that not just the receiving end might have simply classified it as spam? Enable SMTP debugging as a first step, if you haven’t already.

Comment: @CBroe, I just sent it to a mailaddress and check if it arrives. It does, when de $Content is no more then 3 lines. Otherwise it does not, while the script is the same (except the body). How can I enable SMTP debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the issue should be occurring based on what you provided, but defining the variable entirely before assigning it to mail body could solve it, or at least narrow down the issue.

```
$message = 'content<br>';
$message .= 'more content<br>';
$message .= 'yet content<br>';
$mail->Body = $message;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried that. The output of $message is also fine on the screen, but same problem with sending the mail: no more than 3 lines.

Comment: @Jabson does the actual mail that gets sent only have 3 lines, or just when you echo it out? Can you post the line where you echo it? Some output lines truncate data.

Comment: Hello Goose, No, it has many lines, and the echo is ok. But it will only send when I limit the number of lines to max. 3. Otherwise the echo on screen is ok, but no mail is send.

Comment: Currently the code in your question does not give the behavior you describe, so it'll be difficult to help if we don't see the rest of the code. Is there any HTML inside of the variables used in the message. Perhaps there's an open tag that doesn't get closed. Try wrapped each variable in `htmlspecialchars()` to be sure.

Comment: As you see above I've given the complete php-code now. As far as I see there are no open tags or other strange things.

Comment: The values of certain variable, such as `$woonplaats` could contain an unclosed tag, which as of the moment is the only thing that could explain the behavior. If you can hard code the values of the posted variables, confirm that the issue is still occurring, we'll be able to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Oke, I know what the problem is: When I downgrade PHP to 5.6 it works fine. The problem is only with PHP 7.1 and 7.2 with PHPmailer.

When I only send text there is no problem. But when there are some 
 and @ in it the mail is not send.
But as said, with 5.6 there is no problem. For now this problem is solved, and when 5.6 is no longer available at my providere there probably will be an update.